# Question about $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\cos(3x)}{e^{8x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

> $\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{\cos(3x)}{e^{8x}}$

The answer is $0$. Why is the answer $0$? The top oscillates between $-1$  and $1$ and the bottom becomes huge, but since the top is oscillating, shouldn't the answer be DNE (does not exist)?

Comment: The amplitude of the oscillation shrinks to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Notice that for all $x \in \mathbb R$, we have that:
$$
\frac{-1}{e^{8x}} \leq \frac{\cos(3x)}{e^{8x}} \le \frac{1}{e^{8x}}
$$

Comment: Is this the squeeze theorem? could you show some steps to how you would use the Squeeze theorem on this type of problem, thanks +1

Comment: Notice that:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{-1}{e^{8x}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^{8x}} = 0
$$
Combining this with the above inequality, it follows by the Squeeze Theorem that:
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\cos(3x)}{e^{8x}} = 0
$$